# PyCharm: Install Packages Failed

Tags: macos, permissions, pycharm

I need some packages to be installed.
No matter what direction I try, it only gets worse.

[image]

Please help.

> 40:497: execution error: The directory
>   '/Users/doekewartena/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory
>   is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled.
>   Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing
>   pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag. The directory
>   '/Users/doekewartena/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is
>   not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled.
>   check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip
>   with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.   Could not find a version
>   that satisfies the requirement path (from versions: ) No matching
>   distribution found for path  (1)

Comment: Try running pycharm from bash with `sudo -H` appended to the front.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere so you mean "sudo -H install string" like this?

Comment: @alwaysaskingquestions No, `sudo -H pycharm`.

Comment: @alwaysaskingquestions You could do `sudo -H pip install <string>`, but that isn't what I am saying

Comment: @NoOneIsHere so if i want to install the string module, i'd use "sudo -H pycharm install <string>"? but that gives me an error... also your line "sudo -H pycharm" will give me "pycharm: command not found" :(

Comment: @alwaysaskingquestions No. Use `sudo -H pip install <pkg>` to install, and `sudo -H <pycharm command>` to run PyCharm. If pycharm isn't `pycharm`, it won't work. The angle brackets are for you to insert the proper text.

Comment: @NoOneIsHere ahh. Thank you so much! I get it now :)

Answer (score 6):

Did you check file permissions pack for your user ?

You can run the below command to change the ownership of directory (`/Users/doekewartena/Library/Caches/pip`) to your current user (`doekewartena`) :

```
$ sudo chown -R doekewartena /Users/doekewartena/Library/Caches/pip
```

Answer (score 2):

`pip install --user <package-name>` worked for me.

Sudo not required.

Comment: How you install a package highly depends on the individual user's configuration.  Please consider reworking this answer to be more specific to the question.