# Can't update python packages from PyCharm

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, pycharm

Today I installed PyCharm Community 2016.2 on my Mac OS 10.11.6 machine.

In Preferences -> Project Interpreter, my interpreter is python 2.7.10, located here:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7

When I try to upgrade a package (via PyCharm's interface), it prompts me for my admin password, I enter it, and then it fails, outputting this error:

> 40:524: execution error: The directory '/Users/Luke/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

Googling around, I found the StackOverflow advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35895910/pycharm-install-packages-failed), suggesting I run the following from Terminal (my user is "Luke"):

> $ sudo chown -R Luke /Users/Luke/Library/Caches/pip

I did that, but got an error saying there is no such file or directory.

So I checked, and indeed there is no such directory. So, what do I do? Presumably some environmental variable somewhere is wrong? But I don't know where.

Comment: I suggest you get in to the habit of using virtual environments. http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/. And virtualenv is natively in Python 3 already -> https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: You really shouldn't be using the version of Python installed under `/System` - that's an internal version used specifically by the OS for various system tasks, and is not a complete installation for user use. Please download Python 3.5 [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-352/), run the installer, and use it instead. The binary will be `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3`. Add that directory (up to but not including `/python3`) to the *beginning* of your PATH to use it from the command line.